# Laravel 4 - Dinesh/Barcode - QRCode

Tags: php, laravel, package, laravel-4, qr-code

I downloaded this package : http://registry.autopergamene.eu/package/dineshrabara-barcode and i don't understand how does it works.

I would like to generate a QRCode. 
But there is no documents which explain us how to create a basic qrcode.

Someone ever tried this package and can explain me how to proceed ?

Thank you !

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but given the lack of documentation, I suggest looking into [Google API to help you generate a QR code](https://developers.google.com/chart/infographics/). You might be able to even get away with not making any cURL requests and using an <img> tag directly. For example, [this image](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=300x300&cht=qr&chl=Hello%20world).

Comment: Thank you, i seen this API but we can see on this page that "Infographics" is deprecated.

Comment: I also on that problem, but specifically my problem is how to put array of information on the first parameter so that if the user will scan it, he will get something like this:

Name: Joseph
Age: 10

Answer (score 1):

According to [Github Readme](https://github.com/dineshrabara/barcode), you have to:

1) Install it using composer

2) Add to your service providers

3) Publish the configuration

4) And use it this way:

```
 echo '<img src="' . DNS2D::getBarcodePNG("4445645656", "QRCODE",3,33) . '" alt="barcode"   />';

 echo DNS2D::getBarcodeHTML("4445645656", "QRCODE");
```

Comment: Have you tried just `DNS2D::getBarcodePNG("Here Goes Your Basic Text", "QRCODE",3,33)`? What happened?

Comment: Yes, i tried DNS2D::getBarcodePNG("Here Goes Your Basic Text", "QRCODE",3,33) and it's ok for DNS2D, DNS1D..

But for QRcode, there is no example in Readme so i don't know how to create a basic Qrcode.

Answer (score 0):

For generating QR Codes, you need to pass the type of code as 2nd argument. QRCodes are 2D codes, so use DNS2D facade.

**Examples**

```
echo DNS2D::getBarcodeHTML("Text to embed in qr code", "QRCODE");
echo '<img src="data:image/png,' . DNS2D::getBarcodePNG("Text to embed in qr code", "QRCODE") . '" alt="qrcode"   />';
echo DNS2D::getBarcodeSVG("Text to embed in qr code", "QRCODE");
```

Comment: I had to change `<img src="data:image/png,' . DNS2D::getBarcodePNG...` to `<img src="data:image/png,base64,' . DNS2D::getBarcodePNG`